# Testing if $p(A|X,Y) \le p(A|X)$ holds

Tags: probability

Consider three events $A$, $X$ and $Y$. My intuition tells me, for a specific problem that I am working on, that the following inequality may always hold:

$p(A|X,Y) \le p(A|X)$

How do we go about proving (or disproving) it using  [probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms), Bayes rule, or an intuitive example

My attempt using Bayes rule takes me to:

$$p(A|X,Y) = \frac{P(A,X,Y)}{p(X,Y)}$$

$$p(A|X) = \frac{\sum_Y{P(A,X,Y)}}{\sum_Y{p(X,Y)}}$$

so the question is, why would the following satisfy?

$$\frac{P(A,X,Y)}{p(X,Y)} \le \frac{\sum_Y{P(A,X,Y)}}{\sum_Y{p(X,Y)}}$$

Comment: On what is your intuition based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your claim holds, you can take $X$ to be the universal event, and you are implying that $P(A|Y) \le P(A)$ for all $A$ and $Y$, which is false.

Comment: You could strengthen this a little by making $Y = \sim A$ in addition. Still it does the job (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Consider $X=$ "it is Wednesday", $Y=$ "it is raining" and $A=$ "I am carrying an umbrella"

Are you still confident that $P(A|X,Y)\leq P(A|X)$?

[The trick when coming up with an intuitive idea is not to seek confirmatory examples - our natural tendency - but to try to identify examples that would show it to be wrong. It wasn't hard to think of one where $A$ was more likely to be the case when $Y$ held.]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggested going over Chapter 1 and 8 of [Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) to understand why exactly this does not hold. I would start from page 372 onwards and get back to Chapter 1 if I didn't understand any of the concepts there.